# Medium data publish works and Large data publish throws an error? (Node.js & RabbitMQ)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

```
Unhandled connection error: FRAME_ERROR - type 1, 
first 16 octets = <<0,60,0,20,0,0,16,99,108,111,117,100,82,111,117,116>>: {invalid_frame_end_marker,82}
```

I create an exchange that publishes directly to queue 1 with a routing key. Queue 1 then after doing a job on that message publishes to the same exchange to a queue with routing key cl. This is where it throws an error.

File 1
Grab request from server
Create Exchange
Publish on exchange use routing key
Create queue cl
print out message (error occurs when this file receives the message.)

File 2

Queue listening

Get Message from exchange

Work on Message

publish to queue cl

Answer (score -1):

Are you having a problem using the `amqp` module directly? If so, their issue tab on github is probably the best place to report the problem.

If you like, try using my `servicebus` module as well: https://github.com/mateodelnorte/servicebus. `npm install servicebus` will get it for you.